# Pictorially visualise numpy boolean array with strings

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, charts, ascii

Say you have a 2D numpy array of bools, `array`:

```
[[ True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  False False False False True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]]
```

And you wish to represent them pictorially with ██ replacing the `True` values and whitespace for the `False` values:

```
  ██████████████
  ██          ██
  ██████████████
```

I've spent too much time with the chararray to no avail trying things like:

```
chars = np.chararrray(array.shape, unicode=True)
chars[array] = '██'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggested solution works, only need to print it nicer:

```
chars = np.chararray(array.shape, unicode=True)
chars[array] = '██'
print(np.array2string(chars, separator='', formatter={'str_kind': lambda x: x if x else ' '}))
```

I am not sure if you want to get rid of the brackets or not though.

output:

```
[[██████]
 [█    █]
 [██████]]
```

In case you wanted without brackets (disclaimer: this is lazy replacement, you probably can do a better job removing them):

```
print(np.array2string(chars, separator='', formatter={'str_kind': lambda x: x if x else ' '}).replace(" [","").replace("[","").replace("]",""))

██████
█    █
██████
```

Comment: Wow I'm surprised, I got some sort of `IndexError` with my code

Comment: Unsurprisingly perhaps it turns out I'm just an idiot and have mixed up `array.shape` with `array.size` - though I'm gonna blame PIL for being inconsistent with numpy.

Comment: @Krish that happens. I assume everything works now. Otherwise please post error so I can help better. please kindly accept the answer if it solved the issue too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Chararray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.html), is only a backwards compatibility feature that breaks down often. Instead iterate through the array:

```
def __str__(self):
    retval = ''
    for row in self.array:
        retval += ''.join(['  ' if i else '██' for i in row])
        retval += '\n'
    return str(self.array)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not married to the use of a space character for the false entries (which complicates positioning), I suggest the following slightly simplified version, taking inspiration from the previous answers:

```
def print_bool_array(array, true_char='#', false_char='.'):
    chars = np.empty_like(array, dtype=np.str_)
    chars[array] = true_char
    chars[~array] = false_char
    print(np.array2string(chars, separator='', formatter={'all': lambda x: x}
        ).translate(str.maketrans("", "", " []'")))
```