# Visualize a vector of booleans as an image grid of symbols with different colors in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, statistics, visualization, probability

For teaching purposes in statistics and probability, I want to give a visual representation of various probabilities by an image grid with objects or symbols in different colors in a Jupyter notebook.

For instance, by the following code an pixelwise random image is created.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
a = np.random.rand(100, 100)
img = Image.fromarray((a * 255).astype('uint8'), mode='L')
display(img)
```

[image: boolean array depicted as a black and white image]

What I would like to have instead is something like this.

[image]

In order to better visualize the connection between sets and probability.

Comment: on this site, questions need to be *programming* questions. how is this question about programming? [ask], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask]

Comment: A German saying: There are no stupid questions but stupid answers.

Comment: "I would like to have" is a great start, if you wanted to ask a question... but you haven't even said what's keeping you from achieving your goals. if you haven't even read (thoroughly) the first article, please do that. if you still think that your, uh, question, is on topic for this site, then please read the other articles as well. this site is not for *everything* someone might want solved. it's for programming questions that meet a few quality criteria. having done the "research" is one of them. you might want to demonstrate that you've spent the effort.

Comment: as for *your answer* to *my question*, consider applying your quote to the situation ;) don't you think that's fair?

Answer (score 0):

I can provide 3 solutions to this problem.

A random boolean array will be used throughout this answer.

```
import numpy as np
N = 10
p = .75
bool_array = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(N, N), p=[p, 1-p])
```

### Solution 1: Character Printing

Inspired by [Ehsan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755685/pictorially-visualise-numpy-boolean-array-with-strings)

```
ar = bool_array
chars = np.chararray(ar.shape, unicode=True)
true_char = '██'
false_char = ' '
chars[ar] = true_char
print(np.array2string(chars, separator='', formatter={'str_kind': lambda x: x if x else false_char}))
```

### Solution 2: Using matplotlib

Inspired by [P. Camilleri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282368/plotting-a-2d-heatmap)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ar = bool_array
plt.imshow(ar, cmap='hot')
plt.show()
```

### Solution 3: Using mlxtend

Adapted from [this webpage](https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/plotting/heatmap/)

```
from mlxtend.plotting import heatmap
ar = bool_array
heatmap(ar, figsize=(N, N))
plt.show()
```

I think heatmaps are the best way to visualize probability. It is even possible to choose intermediate colors to demonstrate conditional probability.